# Movements bar not showing in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, move

The movements bar in Unity is not showing.

How can I show it
so that it looks like this:
[image]

Unity is showing like that: [image]
Please help me.

Comment: looks like you ran out of resources, hence have of it shows blank squares.. try rebooting, maybe update graphics drivers..

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your computer has ran into a hickup. You might need to restart Unity or possibly your computer to maybe clear out it's cache. There is a chance that something, either in that project or in your Unity install, that got deleted or altered affecting the display.

If restarting everything does not seem to work, maybe try opening another project or version of Unity and see if this continues. If it does, check GPU drivers, reset Unity button layout, or check the bug reports for the Unity version you are using, it could be a known issue already.

If worse comes to worst, you could always use *HotKeys* to select those tools:

- **W:** Select the Move Tool.
- **E:** Select the Rotate Tool.
- **R:** Select the Scale Tool.
- **Q:** Select the Hand Tool (for panning the Scene view).
- **Ctrl (or Cmd on Mac):** Hold down this key to temporarily switch to the Hand Tool while using other tools.
  When using the Move Tool:
- **X:** Toggle between local and global coordinate systems for movement.
- **Y:** Toggle between local and global coordinate systems for movement.
- **Z:** Toggle between local and global coordinate systems for movement.

I am not a professional, but if you have tried all these possibilities and still can't find the issue, you might need to check your computer hardware and see if it is running out of resources.